# Program for interacting with deployed contracts via a GUI?

Tags: truffle

So I've deployed a contract to Rinkbey using truffle, and now I'd like to play with it.

I'd like something that builds a GUI for me from the ABI like EthFiddle does.
I just want something that lists all the functions and lets me type in arguments and call the functions by clicking a button.

Also I dont wanna have to download the blockchain.

Anyone have any way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Several different teams are building platforms to tackle related topics. I'm not sure of the 1st two, but I know the last one listed has on its roadmap to allow autogeneration of GUI components from ABIs and uploaded smart contracts not created from within their platform. (I'm part of the Pactum team)

https://etherparty.com/

https://blockcat.io/

https://pactum.io/

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan creates a user interface for verified contracts.

You can also use https://oneclickdapp.com to generate an interface.